# python: exponent special method?

Tags: python

what is the special method for exponent? For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
    def __pow__(self, power):
        return self.data ** power

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f=Foo(2)
    print(f**3)
```

yields 8 correctly, but when I run `3**f` it says: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'Foo'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should've used `__rpow__` to use like that

**Code:**

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
    def __pow__(self, power):
        return self.data ** power
    def __rpow__(self, power):
        return self.data ** power

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f=Foo(2)
    print(f**3) # 8
    print(3**f) # 8
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: sure, but the system ask me to wait for 9 more minutes.

Comment: @Sam-gege ohh, ok ok, sry

Comment: no prob. thanks! can't believe I haven't tried out __rpow___, I actually implemented __rsub__, __radd__ etc, but I keep trying __exp__ on this one which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be inheriting the int class:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __pow__(self, power):
        return self.x ** power

a = Foo(2)
print(2 ** a)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `f**3`, the interpreter automatically calls `__pow__` method on the object with the integer you gave it(the `__pow__` method is an equivalent for `**` operator ), but it can't interpret any way to use `f` as the power of a number. So you should define another function inside `Foo` class for that usage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).